# Type 'number | { percent: number; }' is not assignable to type 'string | number | undefined' ts(2322)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-state

Currently, I'm working on a `React`, `Typescript` project implementing a progress bar using react `semantic-ui`. So I came up with a typescript error. Here is my code

```
import React, { Component,useState } from 'react'
import { Button, Progress } from 'semantic-ui-react'

export default function ProgressMobileStepper()  {
  //let percent :number
  const [activeStep={percent:0}, setActiveStep] = React.useState(0);
 
  const increment = () => {
    setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep + 5);
  };

  const decrement = () => {
    setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep - 5);
  };
 

  return (
    <>
     <div>  
      <Progress percent={activeStep} indicating color={'red'} size={'small'}/> //error in here percent
      <Button onClick={increment}>Increment</Button>
      <Button onClick={decrement}>Decrement</Button>
     </div>
    </>
  );        
}
```

Comment: `activeStep={percent:0}` why you are initiating like this? 
`const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = React.useState(0);` this works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### The Problem

Your state definition is not correct and causes the error.

```
const [activeStep={percent:0}, setActiveStep] = React.useState(0);
```

You didn't need an object for your state as you are trying to decrease and increase the `activeStep` in the handler functions.

so if you want to define an object as a state, you can easily pass a `{}` as the parameter of `useState`, but in your case, you just need a number for the increase and decrease.

##### The Solution

Change the state definition to properly create a state variable:

```
const [activeSte, setActiveStep] = React.useState(0)
```

###### As a suggest

You don't need to wrap your component with fragment `<></>` since your return statement is all wrapped in a `div` element.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing it from

```
const [activeStep={percent:0}, setActiveStep]
```

To

```
const [activeStep, setActiveStep]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to set initial state then then do it in the `useState` hook,  using desturcturing assignment fallback values is useless as the `useState` hook will *always* return the defined state you set.

Either move the `percent` substate into the hook and update accordingly:

```
//let percent :number
const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = React.useState({ percent: 0 });
 

const increment = () => {
  setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => ({
    percent: prevActiveStep.percent + 5
  }));
};

const decrement = () => {
  setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => ({
    percent: prevActiveStep.percent - 5
  }));
};

...

<Progress
  percent={activeStep.percent}
  indicating
  color={'red'}
  size={'small'}
/>
```

Or don't use a nested `percent` state:

```
//let percent :number
const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = React.useState(0);
 

const increment = () => {
  setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep + 5);
};

const decrement = () => {
  setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep - 5);
};

<Progress
  percent={activeStep}
  indicating
  color={'red'}
  size={'small'}
/>
```